# Hoard C++ Crash

Tags: c++, memory-management, hoard

We are trying to evaluate Hoard in our multithreaded application which runs both on Windows and Mac OSX ( Leopard, Snow Leopard).

We are using Boost, Curl, libJpeg and log4cplusplus as 3rd party libraries. Now, we are linking all our modules with libhoard.dylib but leaving the 3rd party libraries to use system malloc.

Would that cause any conflicts ?

I tried using for the whole application by setting in info.plist DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=libhoard.dylib ( presuming to be equivalent of LD_PRELOAD) but in malloc trace I dont see hoard being picked up.

Is there any other way to link it and use such that even 3rd party libs can use ? Please advice.

Thanks,
Raja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could well cause problem in certain cases. If you allocating something on one heap and freeing it in another you're obviously in for some trouble. Without knowing more detailed information on the structure of your application it's hard to say much more than that.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Is there a way to debug this situation ? Any pointer on MAC OSX as to how we can set it up for the entire application ?